My husband holds an Irish passport, I hold UK passport, can I stay longer than 90 days when accompanying him to Spain
My husband holds an Irish passport I hold UK passport we live in NI, can I stay longer than 90 days when accompanying him to Spain

Is "NI" a typo that should be "NL" ? or do you mean Northern Ireland?

@DavidRecallsMonica did you mean The Netherlands? It's reasonable to suppose that a couple with ROI and UK passports do live in Northern Ireland.

@WeatherVane Yes, I agree. I didn't think of Northern Ireland when I started writing the comment.

I wonder if it is complicated by the fact that none of ROI, NI, and UK are in the Schengen area. Can your husband stay longer than 90 days?

@WeatherVane The freedom of movement directive applies to the whole EU. Being an EU citizen, OP’s husband can live anywhere in the EU, and OP can travel with him or to join in him freely, without time limits (though registration may be required if they stay more than 90 days in the same country).

@DavidRecallsMonica Northern Ireland makes a lot more sense for a couple with Irish and UK citizenships, asking if they can stay in Spain more than 90 days.

@jcaron doesn't registration apply to the Irish citizen too (for more than 90 days)?

@WeatherVane Indeed, hence “they” :-) though of course only if the country they stay in requires it (no idea if that’s the case for Spain and too lazy to check).

@WeatherVane Registration is indeed mandatory for both the OP and her husband. In practice, it's not a big deal if you are only visiting as an EU citizen but it is necessary to get a residence card for the spouse. Without a job, it requires demonstrating sufficient financial means and health insurance for both. Failing to do that would only have limited consequences, though (a fine at most, most likely nothing if you are just visiting a little longer than technically allowed).
